# C++ get 64-bit baseAddress of exe

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to get the base Adress of an exe.
This is working well with x86 applications but it delivers me the wrong start address with x64 processes.
I am using VS2012 compiled to 64-bit running on W7 x64.

```
    static uintptr_t dwGetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwProcessIdentifier, TCHAR *lpszModuleName)
    {
        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessIdentifier);
        BYTE* dwModuleBaseAddress = 0;
        if(hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {               
            MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32 = {0};
            ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

            if(Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32))
            {
                do
                { 
                    if(_tcsicmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0)
                    {                           
                        dwModuleBaseAddress = (BYTE*) ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                        printf("ModuleEntry32.szModule= %S\n", ModuleEntry32.szModule);
                        printf("dwModuleBaseAddress= %p\n", dwModuleBaseAddress);

                        break;
                    }
                }
                while(Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
            }
            CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
        }else{              
            std::cout << "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        return (uintptr_t) dwModuleBaseAddress;
    }
```

This is giving me 137000000 as the baseAdress, which is wrong as stated from CheatEngine.

What am i doing wrong?
The return values and the BYTE* type should be right for ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr.

Any help kindly appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Hmya, why would you trust a "cheat engine" more than the winapi?  Use the debugger, Tools + Attach to Process.  Then Debug + Windows + Modules, look at the Address column.

Comment: Well yes, this was a quick look at the address as i didn´t get any values. When manually taken the start address shown from CE, followed by some depth pointers, the values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, I just ran it on x86 and x64 and in both cases it worked fine.  If you're using this on a x64 process, you must build your exe as x64, if you do that then uintptr_t will correctly resolve to a 8 byte variable.  It looks like you're compiling for x86 and that is your problem maybe.

[image]